# Subclass of numpy ndarray doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, numpy

`Hello, everyone.

I found there is a strange behavior when subclassing a ndarray.

```
import numpy as np

class fooarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        return

a=fooarray(np.random.randn(3,5))
b=np.random.randn(3,5)

a_sum=np.sum(a,axis=0,keepdims=True)
b_sum=np.sum(b,axis=0, keepdims=True)

print a_sum.ndim #1
print b_sum.ndim #2
```

As you have seen, the `keepdims` argument doesn't work for my subclass `fooarray`. It lost one of its axis. How can't I avoid this problem? Or more generally, how can I subclass numpy ndarray correctly?

Comment: One of possible solution is to use `a.sum` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.sum` can accept a variety of objects as input: not only ndarrays, but also lists, generators, `np.matrix`s, for instance. The `keepdims` parameter obviously does not make sense for lists or generators. It is also not appropriate for `np.matrix` instances either, since `np.matrix`s always have 2 dimensions. If you look at the call signature for `np.matrix.sum` you see that its `sum` method has no `keepdims` parameter:

```
Definition: np.matrix.sum(self, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None)
```

So some subclasses of `ndarray` may have `sum` methods which do not have a `keepdims` parameter. This is an unfortunate violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and the origin of the pitfall you encountered.

Now if you look at [the source code for `np.sum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1706), you see that it is a delegating function which tries to determine what to do based on the type of the first argument.

If the type of the first argument is not `ndarray`, it drops the `keepdims` parameter. It does this because passing the keepdims parameter to `np.matrix.sum` would raise an exception.

So because `np.sum` is trying to do the delegation in the most general way, not making any assumption about what arguments a subclass of ndarray may take, it drops the `keepdims` parameter when passed a `fooarray`.

The workaround is to not use `np.sum`, but call `a.sum` instead. This is more direct anyway, since `np.sum` is merely a delegating function.

```
import numpy as np


class fooarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array, *args, **kwargs).view(cls)
        return obj

a = fooarray(np.random.randn(3, 5))
b = np.random.randn(3, 5)

a_sum = a.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
b_sum = np.sum(b, axis=0, keepdims=True)

print(a_sum.ndim)  # 2
print(b_sum.ndim)  # 2
```

Comment: Totally answer my question. Thanks=]

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on @mskimm's comment, if you take a look at the relevant
part of numpy's source code, [`core/fromnumeric.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1706), it's clear why
`a.sum(..., keepdims=True)` works, whereas `np.sum(a, ..., keepdims=True)`
doesn't:

```
def sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
    ...
    if isinstance(a, _gentype):
        res = _sum_(a)
        if out is not None:
            out[...] = res
            return out
        return res
    elif type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
        try:
            sum = a.sum
        except AttributeError:
            return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                                out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
        # NOTE: Dropping the keepdims parameters here...
        return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
    else:
        return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                            out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
    ...
```

Since you've subclassed `np.ndarray`, `type(a)` is `fooarray`, not
`mu.ndarray`, so you end up at this line:

```
# NOTE: Dropping the keepdims parameters here...
return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
```

The `keepdims` keyword argument is a relatively new feature of `ndarrays`, and is not currently implemented for certain other array-like classes such as `np.matrix` or `np.ma.masked_array` which also have a `.sum()` method, hence why that parameter currently gets dropped for non-`ndarray`s.