# Numpy sum() got an 'keepdims' error

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sum, numpy-ndarray

This is a paragraph of a neural network code example:

```
def forward_step(X, W, b, W2, b2):
    hidden_layer = np.maximum(0, np.dot(X, W) + b)
    scores = np.dot(hidden_layer, W2) + b2
    exp_scores = np.exp(scores)
    probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    ...
```

The last line of the code shown above threw an error:

```
<ipython-input-49-d97cff51c360> in forward_step(X, W, b, W2, b2)
     14     scores = np.dot(hidden_layer, W2) + b2
     15     exp_scores = np.exp(scores)
---> 16     probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)
     17     corect_logprobs = -np.log(probs[range(X.shape[0]), y])

/Users/###/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   1810             pass
   1811         else:
-> 1812             return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
   1813     return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
   1814                          out=out, **kwargs)

TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
```

There is a similar question [Numpy sum keepdims error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601131/numpy-sum-keepdims-error) which says that the edition of numpy should be greater than 1.7. I have checked my edition of numpy:

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
>> 1.12.1
```

Now I am confused about how this error occurred.

Comment: Can you give a more explicit example that people can run? I.e. give an example array that has this problem so someone can copy/paste. I'm not getting the error but I'm on numpy 1.13.1.

Comment: To expand a little bit, I'm asking for an example since the [`numpy` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum) do specifically state: "If the sub-classes sum method does not implement keepdims any exceptions will be raised." so I'm wondering if your `exp_scores` is a sub-classed array that doesn't have the `keepdims` implementation. Does it work if `exp_scores = np.ones((10, 10))` or anything?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks for your detailed answer. I was afraid that the whole code is awful so that people would be impatient for it. I have pasted the context of that line, but I am still not sure if the exp_scores here is a sub-classed array that doesn't have the keepdims implementation.

Comment: @AlexRiley I have pasted more traceback. But it still seems a little short. I am just wondering if it is because the jupyter notebook just raises limited traceback information.

Comment: @Leo - ah, thank you. I think it's fairly certain that `exp_scores` is not a NumPy array, as Alexander Reynolds mentions above. The NumPy source shows that line 1812 can only be hit if it is *not* a normal array type: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.12.x/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1806-L1812

Comment: What is `type(exp_scores)`? If `exp_scores` is a numpy *matrix* as opposed to an array, i.e. `type(exp_scores) = <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>` or similar, then you will get this error. If that is the case, you probably don't need to be using numpy matrices, and should switch to arrays unless there's an important reason not to. But if you don't feel like switching your data around before this, you could just cast it to an array the line before you sum.

Comment: it appears to be an [old problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735015/subclass-of-numpy-ndarray-doesnt-work-as-expected) with `keepdims`

Comment: @DanielF I wouldn't call it a *problem*, it's expected behavior and noted directly in the docs. Matrices are always 2D, so any function like `sum` won't reduce the dimensionality, so `keepdims` is a useless parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that under the `keepdims` argument in the [docs for `numpy.sum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum) it states:

> **keepdims** : *bool, optional*
>   If this is set to True, the axes which are reduced are left in the result as dimensions with size one. With this option, the result will broadcast correctly against the input array.
>   If the default value is passed, then *keepdims* will not be passed through to the `sum` method of sub-classes of `ndarray`, however any non-default value will be. If the sub-classes `sum` method does not implement *keepdims* any exceptions will be raised.

So it states here that if you're using a sub-class of `numpy.ndarray`, then you'll get this error if the corresponding `sum` function for the sub-class hasn't been defined with it.

Notice that in your error it references line `1812` in `numpy/core/fromnumeric.py`. Take a look at that in context in the actual [`numpy` 1.12.x source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.12.x/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py):

```
kwargs = {}
if keepdims is not np._NoValue:
    kwargs['keepdims'] = keepdims
if isinstance(a, _gentype):
    res = _sum_(a)
    if out is not None:
        out[...] = res
        return out
    return res
if type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
    try:
        sum = a.sum
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    else:
        return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                     out=out, **kwargs)
```

Two things are important to note here: the `sum` function *did* parse your `keepdims` variable, since it pulled it above line `1812` and tried to put it in another function, so you know the error wasn't the way you used the variable. The other important thing is that the line `1812` which you're erroring on is only executing *if* `type(a) is not mu.ndarray`, i.e., if you're using a different class than `ndarray`. And this is exactly what the documentation is referencing. If you have a different class, then they need to implement this `sum` function *with the keepdims argument*, and if they don't it will raise an error.

Other classes like `np.matrix` for example will have a different sum function, and it seems that, even in `numpy 1.13.x`, `sum` for `np.matrix` types does not support the `keepdim` argument (because in `numpy`, matrices *always* are 2D). For example, it works fine with a `np.array`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.eye(4)
>>> A
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> np.sum(A, axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

But with a `np.matrix`, it doesn't:

```
>>> import numpy.matlib
>>> B = np.matlib.eye(4)
>>> np.sum(B, axis=1, keepdims=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1832, in sum
    return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
```

But, most array/matrix type objects can be easily cast to an array in `numpy` with `np.array(<object>)`, and this should solve the problem for most sub-classed objects in `numpy` and likely your problem. You can also simply wrap the result back into a `np.matrix` if you need to.

```
>>> B = np.matlib.eye(4)
>>> B = np.array(B)
>>> np.sum(B, axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

**However, if your class of object *is* a `np.matrix` type, then the `keepdims` argument is pointless. Matrices are *always* 2D, so the `sum` function won't reduce a dimension, and thus the argument wouldn't do anything. This is why it isn't implemented for matrices.**